# Camel case with lower case words

Tags: naming-conventions, camelcasing

If I had a variable `day`, and I wanted to distinguish it from a class `Day` or something, I would probably write `getday` instead of `getDay`. Is this good practice or is there some better alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Normally when we code according to the coding conversions, It's not a good practice. Use `getDay` format. Its measure your best practice and skill level of proper coding :)

Answer (score 0):

This is kinda opinion based, but `getday` is a little harder to read than `getDay`. The second one is just much cleaner and you can see from the first sight what that metod is about. So I'd go with `getDay`